# Passing environment variables across stages in docker multistage image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment, docker-maven-plugin, multistage

I have a docker image which has 4 lower layers.

I want to reduce the size of my current image layer using multistage, but this causes a loss of environment, port and cmd config properties across the stages. Is there a way to pass on such config variables across stages in `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Can you include a more complete example?  I'd imagine it to be a little unusual to define `EXPOSE` and `CMD` anywhere other than the final stage of a Dockerfile.

Comment: Actually I am worried about environment variables specifically. If somehow I could fetch them from lower layers to final one dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

You can do one of the following

Use a base container and set the environment values there

```
FROM alpine:latest as base
ARG version_default
ENV version=$version_default

FROM base
RUN echo ${version}

FROM base
RUN echo ${version}
```

Other way is to use `ARGS` as below. There is some repetition but it becomes more centralised

```
ARG version_default=v1

FROM alpine:latest as base1
ARG version_default
ENV version=$version_default
RUN echo ${version}
RUN echo ${version_default}

FROM alpine:latest as base2
ARG version_default
RUN echo ${version_default}
```

Note examples copied from https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37345

Comment: Yeah, thanks but this doesn't fetch the variables dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically. Do you want them to be injected at runtime?